# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+\cos2x}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, solution-verification, trigonometric-integrals

This question came in my exam today. The options were:

(a) $\,0$

(b) $\,1/2$

(c) $\,3/2$

(d) I forgot what this option was (they dont let us take the question paper home)

**My attempt:**

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{1+\cos2x}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}[\tan x]_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\tan\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)-0\Big]$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\tan\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)$$

$$=\color{red} {\text{undefined}}$$

Isn't this question wrong?

Comment: Maybe the last option was undefined or divergent.

Comment: d) might have been 'None of the above'.

Comment: Are you sure it was $\cos(2x)$ and not $\cos^2(x)$?

Comment: Yeah, that integral does not converge.  Either there was a "None" option, you misremembered the question, or your instructor made a typo on the test paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)}=
\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta} \frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)}\\=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}
\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}-\delta} \frac{dx}{2\cos^2x} =
\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2}\tan x\,\Big|_{\,0}^{\,\pi/2-\delta}\\ =
\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2}\tan (\pi/2-\delta)=\infty
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2} \frac{dx}{1+\cos(2x)} \stackrel{t=\tan(x)}= \int_0^\infty \frac{\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}{1 + \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}} = \frac12 \int_0^\infty dt \to \infty$$